# Big TiledMap shows black tiles with Cocos Creator

Tags: cocos2d-x, tiled, cocoscreator

I have made a big TiledMap with Tiled tool. The map is 50x500 tiles. Each tile is 48x48 pixel. 
I use "Camera" technique to follow the player on the map.
However I can see only 70% of tiles. Other tiles on the map appears black.
Is the number of tiles rendered by Cocos Creator limited?
Do I need to split the map into multiple parts?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple tilesets? I'm not sure, but cocos2d may still only support a single tileset per layer.

Comment: I use a single tileset per layer. However cocos renders only one piece of the map. I have tried to split the map into two parts and Cocos renders all the tiles successfully. There is a limit that I haven't found in the documentation.